How can I include org-links in org-babel?
I can insert links in plantuml, like this
#+begin_src plantuml
@startuml
actor Bob [[http://plantuml.com/sequence]]
actor "This is [[http://plantuml.com/sequence Alice]] actor" as Alice
Bob -> Alice [[http://plantuml.com/start]] : hello
note left [[http://plantuml.com/start]]
  a note with a link
end note
Alice -> Bob : hello with [[http://plantuml.com/start{Tooltip for message} some link]]
note right [[http://plantuml.com/start]] : another note
note left of Bob
You can use [[http://plantuml.com/start links in notes]] also.
end note
@enduml

, but they are not clickable, meaning I cannot RET on the links.
I'm not talking about clicking on the actual image that is produced, cause that is something which also doesn't work, but I need to focus on this first.
I just want the links inside org-babel to be somehow reachable
I want links to files from org-babel source code blocks;). Is that possible.
What I'm trying to do, it document some piece of software and I want to jump to the code in question, if I f.ex make a class diagram or a sequence diagram.

I don't think you can do that in the Org mode buffer. AFAIK, the body of a src block is an uninterpreted string as far as Org mode is concerned: It is remembered so that it can be passed to the language processor, but nothing else is done with it. In particular, it is not parsed (try M-x org-element-at-point at various places inside the block), so Org does not even know if a "link" is part of that string. OTOH, you might be able to get the links in the output to actually work: you'd have to extend e.g. ob-plantum, perhaps through a derived exporter, to look for "links" and produce ...

... whatever code is appropriate for the language processor to produce active links (I don't know if that's possible with plantuml BTW). Obviously, I have not implemented anything, so a large grain of salt is probably warranted.
